# Как обработать отдельно строки/столбцы в массиве

Tags: c++, массивы

по столбцам массива/ строкам массива необходимо найти минимальные элементы(например), как обратиться отдельно к столбцам/строкам массива?

Comment: Во-первых - что именно в вашем случае представляет из себя этот массив? Лучше всего, покажите код, как он у вас создаётся.

Comment: Массив состоит из целых чисел. Мне надо найти максимальные элементы каждого столбца двумерного массива.Затем из всех максимальных элементов массива найти минимальный.

Comment: И вам к тому же лень скопировать свой код сюда, чтобы на основе вашего кода получали ответ

Comment: Проблема в том что кода своего у меня особо и нет. Я пытаюсь что-то придумать, но пока слаб в программировании. Все что я написал - инициализация массива, и нахождение максимального числа во всем массиве, а как обратиться именно к строке я ума не приложу...

Comment: Так что что из себя представляет строка в вашем массиве? Просто массив - это линейная последовательность, а вам в него нужно впихнуть прямоугольную структуру. Это может быть сделано различными способами, и от того, какой способ используете вы, зависит ответ.

Comment: двумерный массив,не просто массив, извините. состоит из чисел

Comment: int Arr[m][n] = { {2,0,-2},
                   {4,6,8},
                   {3,8,12}
                 }; //например даже так

Comment: А в обычном одномерном массиве вы понимаете как найти минимальный элемент?

Comment: да, это умеем) вопрос не в этом, вопрос был в прохождении по строкам/столбцам двумерного массива

Answer (score 0):

Проходите по строкам

```
for(int i = 0; i < Число_столбцов; i++) {
    Работа с элементом A[Нужная_строка][i]
```

или столбцам

```
for(int i = 0; i < Число_строк; i++) {
    Работа с элементом A[i][Нужный_столбец]
```

и делаете то, что вам надо.

Comment: огромное спасибо